# How to access singleton class from service when the app is not running

Tags: android, android-service

I have created a singleton class User, and I am setting some values in the class from activities. I am using those values for the service (which I am calling from Broadcast receiver). When the app is running, the service gets the values from the User claa. But, when the app is not running, the service is receiving null values.

Is there any other way to store and access the values that I am doing above wiht Singleton class which the app can use in the background?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about create the singleton in `Application.onCreate`?

Comment: Use `SharedPreferences`, an SQLite database, or a file.

Comment: @DavidWasser I tried with the file method already. File operations are taking time. SharedPreferences are not working

Comment: What do you mean by "not working". Show more code. `SharedPreferences` should work fine.